# CSS bug on brave/chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm doing a bit of CSS on cssbattle.dev, and I'm using the box-shadow property

I know very well that a box-shadow is supposed to follow the border-radius of its element. It did work really well the last time I did it but now it's absolutely broken on Brave and Chrome, through it's still working on Firefox for example.

I'm looking for both an explanation and a solution

```
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #0B2429
  }
  #a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 50% 0 50%;
    background: #998235;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
  #b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0B2429;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px #F3AC3C, 0 0 0 65px #0B2429;
  }
</style>
```

Here is the code, and here is what I want to do https://cssbattle.dev/play/16

Comment: Please provide the code which you tried and did not work for so that someone can help.

Comment: Please put code direct into your question. We cannot see it ion the cssbattle site.

Comment: @AHaworth that's what I did

Comment: I have run your code on Firefox, Edge and Chrome (all on Windows 10) and on IOS 15.4 Safari and they all seem to give the same outcome (a sort of eye shape). What version Chrome and what OS are you using and what does it look like on Chrome for you compared to what it should look like? Incidentally, if you make your code into a runnable snippet you may attract more people to try it out.

Comment: looks like the size of the box is too small to draw a complete round(circle) shadow that big. Use a backgroudn gradient instead an extra round box ;) here an example to test/demonstrate the behavior https://jsfiddle.net/njctkqxe/

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using brave and chrome both on the 105 version, same for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why it doesn't work on Chrome. Please find below the code demonstrating the box-shadow and you should be able to see very clearly that it works.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

Unless you are doing something else. In this case, you might want to share your code so that I can help.

Comment: Yup sorry, I've edited my question with my code and what I am aiming to, 
the difference is that I'm with a completely round div and a big shadow